# Problem combining hyperref and imakeidx in book parts

Tags: cross-referencing, book-design, imakeidx

I have a book with different parts. I number the chapters and pages per part, using the `\numberwithin` command. I have defined an index per part using `{imakeidx}` and `{hyperref}`. The indices list the correct page number in the part, but the hyperlinks always go to the first part.

It appears that I have to redefine the destination page to resolve the page number ambiguity. I couldn't get it working, like getting `{hyperref}` to use `\theHpage`.

I enclose a working example which demonstrates this problem below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\indexsetup{level=\section*,toclevel=section,noclearpage,firstpagestyle=empty}
 \makeindex[name=subjectsI,title=Subject index Part I,intoc,columns=3]
  \makeindex[name=subjectsII,title=Subject index Part II,intoc,columns=3]
%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\idxs}[1]{{#1}\index[subjectsI]{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\idxsII}[1]{{#1}\index[subjectsII]{#1}}
%
\usepackage{amsmath,amsbsy}
%
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=black,pageanchor,
hypertexnames]{hyperref}
%
% numbering chapters and pages per part
\numberwithin{chapter}{part}
\numberwithin{page}{part}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\numberwithin{table}{chapter}
%
% BOOK
%
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
%
%PART I
%
\setcounter{page}{1}
\part{This is Part I}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%
\chapter{ Chapter one-one}
\section{Section one-one-one}
All of us have witnessed how science has profoundly affected  the human condition and transformed society, and how in many instances it managed to transcend man's painful political, ethnic, and \idxs{religious differences}. As such it is a true \idxs{cornerstone} of civilization. 
%
\chapter{Chapter one-two}
\section{Section one-two-one}
It expresses the \idxs{collective curiosity} of mankind and has resulted in a double helix of science and technology that  keeps transforming our world over and again. 
%
%INDICES PART I
%
\chapter*{Indices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Indices}
\printindex[subjectsI]
\cleardoublepage
%
%PART II
%
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\part{This is Part II}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%
\chapter{Chapter two-one}
\section{Section two-one-one}
 I go deeper and deeper, as I concentrate on writing, into a kind of \idxsII{underground}. While I'm there, I encounter strange things.
%
\chapter{Chapter two-two}
\section{Section two-two-one}
So I look around that world and I describe what I see, and then I come back. Coming back is important. If you cannot come back, it's scary. But I'm a \idxsII{professional}, so I can come back.
%
%INDICES PART II
%
\chapter*{Indices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Indices}
\printindex[subjectsII]
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit the question and remove all content unrelated to the problem and not needed to replace it. Also put the code in a code block, because the above is unreadable.

Comment: Thanks, I did reduce the example to an MWE.

Comment: Just wondering: what is up with the options to the `geometry` package?

Comment: Indeed, it is a superfluous  left over of original file and can be omitted!

Comment: My MWE did not work because of typo, now it does!